# How to get "The Stallman"?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash-2013

How do I get the **[The Stallman](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/the-stallman)** hat. It mentioned ***edit a community wiki post***, but I edited some post which is bumped on the main page like the screenshot below and have not yet received that hat. Do I understand it wrongly? If so, where can I find the community wiki post?

> [image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: I know, I will get down vote for asking basic question, but honestly I don't know this.

Comment: You could just type "community wiki" in the search box, the faq appears first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a community wiki post. That is just a post which has been bumped by the Community user. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) question for more information on Community Wiki posts. A community wiki post is a post that the author of an answer thinks should belong to the community and not to them. Questions can also be converted to Community Wiki but only by a mod or dev. The user who posted the Wiki post doesn't get any rep for upvotes or lose rep for downvotes. Anyone can change it given they have 100 rep. An example of a community wiki post is the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: Your answer contains wrong and misleading information. Only moderator can mark a question as community wiki, ordinary users can mark only (their own) answers as CW.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You're right, I thought that I could mark my own questions as CW, apparently not.

Comment: Correct now, though not complete - other things can make a post into CW but we won't get into this here. (already linked to the faq)

Answer (score 0):

Posts sporting the "Community" user for one reason or another are not the same as *community wiki* posts. You appear to have conflated these.

Also, doing stuff just for the hats is dubious. Just sayin'...

Comment: The post he edited wasn't owned by the community user, just edited by it. (either auto bump or anonymous approved edit)